# 2017 MacBook Pro A1708 died suddenly when connecting to USB-C power while waking from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake

I have a 2017 MBP, it's nearly two years old, and I don't have AppleCare. I did get the keyboard serviced about a month and a half ago before the COVID closures. I am on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Today, the laptop was sleeping when I touched the keyboard while plugging in the power. I use Apple's official power brick that came with the computer, and had replaced the USB-C Cable with a new official Apple cable about a month ago. The keyboard lit up, but before the screen turned on, I finished plugging in the USB-C power cable. The keyboard immediately went dark, the screen never turned on the backlight, and repeated attempts to get the laptop to boot or show any signs of life have failed.

I've tried holding down the power button repeatedly, with the cable plugged in and not plugged in, and an SMC reset 4 times, but the laptop refuses to show any signs of activity.

Because it was waking from sleep, I'm almost wondering if I had a kernel panic from the 10.15.4+SupplementalUpdate issues, and the laptop isn't resetting. (I don't know if I have the Supplemental update installed or not. I previously prevented it from installing, but perhaps it installed overnight?) This would imply an SMC problem, as my model has no T1/T2 chip (being from 2017 and no touch bar).

Any ideas on how to fix it myself would be tremendously helpful. I am a college student and have finals in 3 weeks. I talked with Apple and they said to send it to an AASP, but had no idea what it would cost to fix, which is simply too much time and money in my situation. I have a pentalobe screwdriver coming next week, so I'm hoping that disconnecting the battery will solve the problem.